# Insert list of strings into 2d vector

Tags: c++, list, vector, iterator, 2d-vector

I'm trying to take a list, and depending on the string in the list, creates a new row in the 2d vector. I am newer to c++ and have a few questions:

1) Am I able to iterate through the list, and grab the string that the iterator is currently at? If so, how am I able to add that string into the vector?

2) How am I able to implement that in a 2d vector?

3) When initializing the 2d vector, would pushback work to be able to increase the size as you insert each element? I currently initalize it at 10, but would like to initalize it at 0, and increase the vectors as I insert strings. (Not sure if that's the best approach)

```
std::vector<std::vector<string> >myVector(10, std::vector<string>(10));
std::list<string> myList;
list<string>::iterator i;
inputList(myList);

int vectorRow = 0;
int vectorCol = 0;

//Insert list into vector
for (i = myList.begin(); i != myList.end(); i++) {
    //add to the current row of the vector
    if (*i == "endOfRow"){
        vectorRow++;
        vectorCol = 0;
    } else {
        //add to the column of the vector
     vectorCol++;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Am I able to iterate through the list" - I dunno, are you? - "and grab the string that the iterator is currently at?" - what would be the point of iterating if you couldn't?

Comment: To check whether it has a value, or whether it has a certain amount of values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think more context is needed here but I'm guessing what you want is something like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<string> > myVector(1);
std::list<string> myList;
inputList(myList);

//Insert list into vector
for (list<string>::iterator i = myList.begin(); i != myList.end(); i++) {
    //add to the current row of the vector
    if (*i == "endOfRow"){
        myVector.push_back(std::vector<string>());
    } else {
        //add to the column of the vector
        myVector.back().push_back(*i);
    }
}
```

> 1) Am I able to iterate through the list, and grab the string that the iterator is currently at? If so, how am I able to add that string into the vector?

You could, but you can also just get the string your iterator points to by dereferencing it, e.g. if your iterator is called `iter`, then you just write `*iter`. I'm confused though because your example seems to already do this.

> 2) How am I able to implement that in a 2d vector?

Need to figure out what you're really trying to do by working through question 1 before answering this.

> 3) When initializing the 2d vector, would pushback work to be able to increase the size as you insert each element?...

Yes.

> ...I currently initalize it at 10, but would like to initalize it at 0, and increase the vectors as I insert strings. (Not sure if that's the best approach)

Yeah using `push_back` as you go is fine. If you know you're going to need a lot of capacity and are concerned about efficiency, consider using [`vector::reserve`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/).

Comment: I figured you could grab the string with the iterator, just was having issues with it, so I wanted to make sure it was possible.

Comment: I'll give the reserve a shot as well!

Answer (score 1):

```
std::list<std::string> myList;
inputList(myList);

std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>myVector(1);        
for (const auto& str : myList) 
{
    if (str == "endOfRow")
        myVector.push_back({});
    else
        myVector.back().emplace_back(str);
}

if (myList.empty()) 
    myVector.clear();

// there is no need to update these values inside the loop
int vectorRow = (int)myVector.size();
int vectorCol = (int)myVector.back().size();
```

> 1) Am I able to iterate through the list, and grab the string that the
>   iterator is currently at? If so, how am I able to add that string into
>   the vector?

Yes. The way you are doing it is correct, though you can use better syntax. To add it to the vector, just emplace_back() or push_back().

> 3) When initializing the 2d vector, would pushback work to be able to
>   increase the size as you insert each element?

It will. But as you said, if you know the size of the list in the beginning, you can easily initialize it to make it more optimized. If you don't want to initialize the vector, but still want to reserve the space, you can also use vector.reserve()